# Cannot Load Library "./pxcore.so" to autorun a python script on boot using systemd

Tags: python, pi-3, boot, debian

**I want to run a code at startup but I am getting this error below. The script works when running in python, but I am unsure how to allocate permissions or where to make a path to the pxcore.so file so this startup service will work. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.**

```
sudo systemctl status autodetect.service
● autodetect.service - Auto Detect Service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/autodetect.service; enabled)
Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2017-06-13 20:21:21 CDT; 10s ago
Process: 1145 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/pixetrpi/autodetect.py  (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
Main PID: 1145 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

Jun 13 20:21:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Auto Detect Service.
Jun 13 20:21:21 raspberrypi python[1145]: Cannot load library  "./pxcore.so": ./pxcore.so: cannot open shared object file: No such fi...rectory
Jun 13 20:21:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: autodetect.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jun 13 20:21:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit autodetect.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

**The service I have created is:**

```
[Unit]
Description= Auto Detect Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/pixetrpi/autodetect.py
WorkingDirecory=/home/pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Which runs this autodetect.py script I created:**

```
import pypixet

from time import sleep

import acquisition_example

def autodetect(pixet):
devices = pixet.devices()

while str(type(devices[0])) != "<type 'IDevMpx2'>":
    print(devices)
    sleep(1)
    devices = pixet.devices()
return pixet.devices().pop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
device = autodetect(acquisition_example.pixet)
print("Discovered minipix!")
acquisition_example.acqExample1()
```

Comment: You have to know where `pxcore.so` is located. Where is it with full path?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue could be that you have multiple versions of python (just talking by experience, might be wrong).

I had similar issues in the past with python/systemctl, you should try to include something like **#!/usr/bin/python**. This way you tell the service running the script, which interpreter to use and where to find it. This question talks a little about shebang lines, if you want more info on this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script

I'm not 100% sure this will fix it, but i think you should give it a try, since for example the version of python used by your systemctl service to run your script, may not have that library installed.